# Does socket work in mobile data such as 3G/4G?

Tags: sockets

In socket using wifi, I can transfer my data by setting IP address and port number in Android Server and C# Client socket.

But now,if I am using mobile data like 3G,4G for internet connection, I have no idea how to send data using socket. Please any idea of socket using 3G/4G?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, sockets are not allowed by operators. They block incoming connections. You should use HTTP requests instead.